# Asymptotic expansion of the given integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, special-functions

How to find the first few terms in the asymptotic expansion of the given integral, as z tends to infinity, $$\int_0^\infty dt \left\{\frac{t-(e^ t -1)}{t(e^ t-1)}+1/2 \right\}e^{-tz} $$ Does this possess any relation to digamma function?

Comment: Laplace's method looks like it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near $t=0$ an expansion is $$\frac{t-(e^t-1)}{t(e^t-1)}+\frac{1}{2}\sim \frac{t}{12}-\frac{t^3}{720}+\frac{t^5}{30240}...  $$ then, [Watson lemma](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3) applies
$$ I\sim \frac{1}{12z^2}-\frac{1}{120z^4}+...$$

Comment: this is in accordance with my experiments (+1)